# Required Gear ratio for a DC motor

Tags: dc-motor, gear

I am making a dc motor vehicle, it will have 2 drive wheels each powered by a separate motor. For a desired speed and acceleration, how would I go about calculating the gear ratio needed?

Info I have obtained:
- Torque vs. Angular Speed Curve equation: y = -6E-6x + 0.0059
- Therefore Theoretical Torque Max = 0.0059 Nm and theoretical angular speed max =983.33 rad/s.
- Mass of Vehicle ~ 1.150kg
- Desired Speed 0.3 m/s
- Desired acceleration  =0.1m/s^2

I am unsure which equations to use to get a proper gear ratio as to get the desired speed without overworking the motor. Note: the voltage applied is constant at about 4.5 V, it cannot be changed.
Wheel radius is 37.5mm

Comment: need to know radius of wheels

Comment: @JonRB The radius is 37.5mm

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't this type of question be better suited for the Engineering SE? You're asking about a DC motor, granted, but there is no electrical engineering involved in calculating a gear ratio. You've already got an answer, so I guess go with it, but for next time, you would be better served at the Engineering SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many contributing factors to this, most of which is related to frictional force, incline etc. If we ignore these for a moment

If we start off with \$F = ma \$ [1]

and equally \$ T = F*r\$ [2]

Where

- m = mass of vehicle
- r = radius of wheels
- \$T_w\$ = torque at wheels (post gearbox)
- \$T_m\$ = torque at motor (pre gearbox)
- F = force to accelerate the mass
- \$\omega_w \$ = velocity of the wheel
- \$\omega_m \$ = velocity of the motors rotor
- R = gearbox ratio.

\$\frac{T_w}{r} = ma  \$ [3]

if \$T_m = -6\mu \omega_m  + 0.0059 \$  [4]

and thus

\$T_w = -6\mu \frac{\omega_w}{R}  + 0.0059 \$ [5]

substituting back into [3]

\$\frac{-6\mu \frac{\omega_w}{R}  + 0.0059}{r} = ma \$ [6]

now it is stated the desired speed is 0.3m/s

The circumference of the wheel is \$2 \pi r\$ & thus

\$speed  = \omega_w  r \$  [7]

thus  \$\omega_w = \frac{0.3}{ r}\$ [8]

substituting [8] into [6] and rearranging for R:

\$ R = \frac{-6\mu * 0.3}{0.00375*(0.1*1.150*0.00375-0.0059)} = 0.08777\$  or rounded up... 12:1 gearbox

Comment: correct me if im wrong, but isnt 37.5 mm 0.0375m?

Comment: also, what is u?

Comment: also, did you account for 2 motors?